# Depth-first search with discovery and finish time using Stack but without recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am implementing Depth-first search algorithm. There are two requirements: I must use Stack (no Recursion), and it should also returns the discovery time and finish time. Here is the code using recursion I implemented:

```py
def dfs(graph, source):
    """Depth-first search algorithm

    This function computes depth-first search and prints the nodes as it travels

    Arguments:
        graph: List[List[int]], adjacency matrix of the graph
        source: int, the starting point
    Returns:
        None
    """
    visited = [False] * len(graph)
    time_start = [0] * len(graph) # Time when vertex is discovered
    time_finish = [0] * len(graph) # Time when vertex has finished discovering
    time = 0
    dfs_visit(graph, source, visited, time, time_start, time_finish)
    return time_start, time_finish

def dfs_visit(graph, source, visited, time, time_start, time_finish):
    time += 1
    time_start[source] = time
    visited[source] = True
    print(source, end = " ")
    for i, val in enumerate(graph[source]):
        if not visited[i] and val != 0:
            dfs_visit(graph, i, visited, time, time_start, time_finish)
    time += 1
    time_finish[source] = time
```

Sample input:

```py
graph = [[0, 1, 1, 0], 
         [1, 0, 1, 0], 
         [1, 1, 0, 1], 
         [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Expected output: `2 0 1 3 ([2, 3, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2, 3])` where the first array indicates discovery time and the second indicates finish time (by index).

Taken that idea I implemented the DFS using Stack:

```py
def dfs_stack(graph, source):
    """Depth-first search algorithm using stack

    This function computes depth-first search and prints the nodes as it travels

    Arguments:
        graph: List[List[int]], adjacency matrix of the graph
        source: int, the starting point
    Returns:
        None
    """
    visited = [False] * len(graph)
    dfs_visit(graph, source, visited)
    return time_start, time_finish

def dfs_visit(graph, source, visited):
    stack = []
    stack.append(source)

    while (len(stack)):
        s = stack[-1]
        stack.pop()
        if not visited[s]:
            print(s, end = " ")
            visited[s] = True
        for idx, val in enumerate(graph[s]):
            if (not visited[idx]) and val != 0:
                stack.append(idx)
```

I try to put `time += 1; time_start[s] = ...` to calculate these time but it outputs weird result. Where should I put the time counter correctly?

Comment: `time_start[s] = time` should happen as soon as you "visit" a node for the first time, ie, just after popping it from the stack, under `if not visited[s]`.

Comment: `time_finish` is more complex to handle; the recursion version **returned** from the recursive calls, so there was an implicit way back from the children nodes to the parent node. I think the easiest way to emulate this behaviour is to push parent node on stack before pushing children. Instead of adding index of node to stack, add pair (index, string) where string says "parent" or "child".Then go like this: when popping an unvisited "child": pop child; mark time_start; push it back as "parent"; push children as "child". when popping an unvisited "parent": mark time_finish; don't push anything.

Comment: Yeah I see that the `time_finish` is very hard to do. I will try your suggestion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interestingly, function calls, and thus recursion, are implemented using a stack. When a function call is made, the state of execution in the currently-executed function remains on the stack, and the new function call is added on the stack. This allows code like `print("before"); recursive_call(); print("after");`. Your current code removes the "current node" from the stack with `stack.pop()` before pushing new nodes on the stack; this is why you could only do the equivalent of `print("before"); recursive_call();`.

Comment: To fix this, you need to leave the current node on the stack, but add info so you know if it's "before" or "after" when you examine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a few remarks about your code:

#### Concerning the recursive solution

The times that are logged are somewhat confusing, as you have duplicate timestamps (e.g. 3). This is because the increments you make to `time` are not fed back to the caller, which has its own `time` variable instance. I would make `time` a non local variable, so that it keeps incrementing.

So I would change that to:

```
def dfs(graph, source):
    def dfs_visit(graph, source, visited, time_start, time_finish):
        nonlocal time
        time += 1
        time_start[source] = time
        visited[source] = True
        print(source, end = " ")
        for i, val in enumerate(graph[source]):
            if not visited[i] and val != 0:
                dfs_visit(graph, i, visited, time_start, time_finish)
        time += 1
        time_finish[source] = time

    visited = [False] * len(graph)
    time_start = [0] * len(graph)
    time_finish = [0] * len(graph)
    time = 0
    dfs_visit(graph, source, visited, time_start, time_finish)
    return time_start, time_finish
```

Now the output of `print(dfs(graph, 2))` will be:

```
2 0 1 3 ([2, 3, 1, 6], [5, 4, 8, 7])
```

This makes more sense to me, but maybe I misunderstood what you intended to do with `time`.

#### Concerning the iterative solution

- `s = stack[-1]` followed by `stack.pop()` can really be written as `s = stack.pop()`
- You are pushing *all* children of a node unto the stack *before* processing their children. This means that actually the depth-first traversal will visit children from last-to-first, while your recursive implementation visits them from first-to-last.

## Logging finishing times

Now to the core of your question. If you want to register the finishing time of a visit, you'll need to leave a trace of the node on the stack, and only remove it from that stack when all its children have been processed; not earlier.

One way to achieve that, is to store on the stack which was the last neighbor that was visited from the node. So you would store (node, neighbor) tuples. If no next node had been visited yet from that node, then the initial value for `neighbor` could be -1.

Here is how that would work:

```
def dfs_stack(graph, source):
    visited = [False] * len(graph)
    time_start = [0] * len(graph)
    time_finish = [0] * len(graph)
    time = 0
    stack = [(source, -1)]
    while stack:
        node, neighbor = stack.pop()
        if neighbor == -1:
            if visited[node]:
                continue
            visited[node] = True
            print(node, end = " ")
            time += 1
            time_start[node] = time
        try:
            neighbor = graph[node].index(1, neighbor + 1)
            stack.append((node, neighbor))
            if not visited[neighbor]:
                stack.append((neighbor, -1))
        except ValueError:  # no more neighbors...
            time += 1
            time_finish[node] = time
```

If we call this with `print(dfs_stack(graph, 2))` we also get:

```
2 0 1 3 ([2, 3, 1, 6], [5, 4, 8, 7])
```

Comment: The `time` variable can be either way, as long as it tells us the time, but to avoid confusion I will use yours. Very helpful, thanks a lot!